# Is std::adjacent_find(last, last) undefined?

Tags: c++, algorithm, language-lawyer

[`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)

> searches the range [`first`, `last`) for two consecutive identical elements.
>
> #### Return value
>
> an iterator to the first of the first pair of identical elements, that is, the first iterator `it` such that `*it == *(it+1)` for the first version or `p(*it, *(it + 1)) != false` for the second version.
>
> If no such elements are found, last is returned

However, it is not clear how it is supposed to handle the range {`last`, `last`}.

Both possible implementations on cppreference have the following check:

```
if (first == last) {
    return last;
}
```

Is `std::adjacent_find(last, last)` UB or the standard does define it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's well-defined.

Quoting C++ standard draft N4296, Section 25.2.8/1:

> *Returns*: The first iterator `i` such that both `i` and `i + 1` are in the range `[first,last)` for which the
>   following corresponding conditions hold: `*i == *(i + 1)`, `pred(*i, *(i + 1)) != false`. **Returns
>   `last` if no such iterator is found.**

So, if `first == last`, it means the search range is empty, and thus the method should return `last`.

The check on CppReference is very correct. It is also [mentioned on CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find#Return_value) that:

> If no such elements are found, `last` is returned

Comment: cppreference misses this important part "such that both `i` and `i + 1` are in the range [`first`,`last`)", so it is incomplete.

Comment: @DevNull *searches the range for **two consecutive** elements* I think that's clear enough.

Comment: @DevNull You know that `[last, last)` is an empty range where there's nothing to search, so `last` can be returned directly, no?

Comment: The wording in the standard that you quoted (thanks!) is more explicit. I know what "[`first`,`last`)" means, however, article on cppreference doesn't make it absolutely clear that `last` will not be deferenced.